# Present continuous in time clauses with "after"

Tags: tense, present-continuous, subordinate-clauses

I'm not sure if I can use the present continuous in the following sentence:

> "I'll take a trip to the States after I'm finishing my studies"

Should I use the present simple or present perfect?

Comment: Your version is syntactically invalid. Use either *...after **I finish** my studies* or *...after **I have finished** my studies* (with subject explicitly repeated) OR *...after **finishing** my studies* (don't repeat the subject ***I***). Or even *...after **having finished** my studies*, but that's relatively uncommon when referencing a ***future*** situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should. Your studies will be finished at a specific, definite time in the future, and you're saying you'll take your trip after that time. So, either:

> I'll take a trip to the States **after I finish** my studies.

or...

> I'll take a trip to the States **when I finish** my studies.

Sequencing words like "after" and "before" can't be used with the continuous aspect.